# Quickblox push going to sender as well as receivers

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have quickblox almost working on ios. The last problem is when I send a push notification I get it on the sender too. Presumably this is not intentional?

Curiously when I look at the debug output from quickblox I see that it has repeated one of the receiver ids. The NSString I pass in toUsers is "678004, 681456, 683185"

`[QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:receivers delegate:self];`

and I see that in the initial Quickblox debug output

```
parameters:{
"event[environment]" = development;
"event[event_type]" = "one_shot";
"event[message]" = "payload=eyJhcHMiOnsiYWxlcnQiOiJEaXJrIFdvb2Qgc3RhcnRlZCB1c2luZyBCbG9jIHRvZGF5IiwibmV3cyI6MzQ0NDg1NTQ3OTEsInNvdW5kIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsInBtdGlrIjoyfX0=";
"event[notification_type]" = push;
"event[push_type]" = apns;
"event[user][ids]" = "678004, 681456, 683185";
```

}

but then in the RestResponse debug output I see

`body:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>
  <active type="boolean">true</active>
  <application-id type="integer">4637</application-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2014-01-23T17:02:40Z</created-at>
  <date type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <end-date type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <event-type>one_shot</event-type>
  <id type="integer">1073359</id>
  <message>payload=eyJhcHMiOnsiYWxlcnQiOiJEaXJrIFdvb2Qgc3RhcnRlZCB1c2luZyBCbG9jIHRvZGF5IiwibmV3cyI6MzQ0NDg1NTQ3OTEsInNvdW5kIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsInBtdGlrIjoyfX0=</message>
  <name nil="true"/>
  <occured-count type="integer">0</occured-count>
  <period type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2014-01-23T17:02:40Z</updated-at>
  <user-id type="integer">681447</user-id>
  <notification-channel>
    <name>apns</name>
  </notification-channel>
  <subscribers-selector>
    <environment>development</environment>
    <tags-query nil="true"/>
    <user-ids type="array">
      <user-id type="integer">678004</user-id>
      <user-id type="integer">681456</user-id>
      <user-id type="integer">683185</user-id>
      <user-id type="integer">681456</user-id>
    </user-ids>
  </subscribers-selector>
</event>`

where the second user has been repeated, and the sender receives the notification.
I don't know whether it would have any significance but one of the user is running on the simulator - wouldn't expect to see a notification there.

Comment: Are you remove app without push unsubscription? I have same problem, when login as user 1, remove app and login into app as user 2. After then I send push to user 1 and receive push on sender side.

Comment: @frankWhite nope - I am using several separate devices to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what is going on here:

```
<user-ids type="array"> 
    <user-id type="integer">678004</user-id> 
    <user-id type="integer">681456</user-id> 
    <user-id type="integer">683185</user-id> 
    <user-id type="integer">681456</user-id> 
</user-ids>
```

It means that 4 devices will receive this push notifications. User with ID 681456 has 2 devices. That's why you can see 2 same ids 681456 and 681456 here.

Look's like one of your receiver was subscribed on sender's device too.

You can check user's devices in admin panel and manage them - open [Admin panel](http://admin.quickblox.com), Users module, edit user - you will see all user's devices [image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.